# Is it possible to use all the space in app section and increase icon size more than the maximum size in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS?

Tags: icons, customization

[image]

In this screen there is a lot of **unused space** which can be used. It requires me to scroll to see more icons and go to next page and other pages. Is there a way to consolidate all icons in one page? How can this be done by command line? Right now this looks like more of an android screen rather than a desktop screen. A very desired feature in Ubuntu.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time at Askubuntu.

Comment: Ok! I have edited this question now. Asking the second question in new thread. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your first request can be done with Gnome extensions.

In particular you may use [More columns in applications view](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1305/more-columns-in-applications-view/)

Not sure how to increase icon size though.

Comment: Thanks a ton!! I have successfully did it. Still there is some space but it is great that at least this much is achieved!! Thank you very much. Now only second request is remaining. :)

Comment: Hi! On searching for an icon name does it show up after we use this extension for increasing the array size? I am getting this following image no matter what application I search. It shows searching but cannot see any application: https://i.postimg.cc/yNZBHMnt/Screenshot-from-2021-01-07-23-44-23.png